# How to generate ID i created in java class to r.java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

im new to android programming.

im wondering if it is possible to generate ID i created in java class to r.java

The ID i want to generate is nBtnLayoutlist.

```
public class classABC extends Activity {
    private int nBtnLayoutlist = 20;

    private OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            nBtnLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.nBtnLayoutList);

            }
        };
    }

    private LinearLayout newBtnLayout(){
    LinearLayout nBtnLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    nBtnLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    nBtnLayout.setLayoutParams(lparams); 
    nBtnLayout.setWeightSum(100);
    nBtnLayout.setId(nBtnLayoutList);
    return nBtnLayout;

}
```

Comment: but im having a new problem 

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471031/android-linearlayout-null-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ids in R.java are generated at build time from the contents of your .xml files. R.java cannot be modified by hand and it cannot be modified at run time.

If you want, you can define an [id resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) by declaring it in some file in `res/values` (the file can have any name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item
        type="id"
        name="id_name" />
</resources>
```

You can always set the id of a view in your layout by calling `setId(int)` (as you are already doing).

EDIT: If you want to use a constant in the call such as

```
nBtnLayout.setId(nBtnLayoutList);
```

then you need to use the same constant in calls such as

```
nBtnLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(nBtnLayoutList); // NOT R.id.nBtnLayoutList
```

Comment: sry i miss out the declaration of the nBtnLayoutList

Comment: @user903933 - Are you asking if you can just use an ID like that, independent of R.java? If so, the answer is "yes". But unless there was a need to generate IDs dynamically, I would define the ID as a resource to ensure that there is no collision between your ID and any build-generated ID values. (The chances of a collision are small, but why leave it to chance?)

Answer (score 0):

**-** `nBtnLayoutList` is a reference to the LinearLayout.

**-** You can set id to the `LinearLayout` by passing integer in `setId()` method.

**Eg:**

```
nBtnLayout.setId(1);
```